# Getting primary key value of recently added record in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

For the web app that I am working on, whenever a user adds a new record to the database, the system validates if the record has successfully been added or not:

```
if (txnHnd.AddNewTxnDetails(txnDetails) == true && txnHnd.AddNewTxnName(txnName) == true)
{
   string message = "Record has been saved.";
   lblErrorMsg.Text = message;
   Response.Redirect("FXTxnList.aspx");
}
else
{
   string message = "Saving record failed.";
   lblErrorMsg.Text = message;
}
```

Now, IF the record has been successfully added, only then will the system insert a sort of `Reference Number` to the newly-added record. My table has a primary key called `TxnID` of type `int`. It's an auto-increment number BTW. The question is, how do I extract the TxnID of the newly added record from the database? I need to put the code inside the `if` part of the `if-else` statement, where it says that the Record has been saved.

Comment: If you are using a SP you can return newly created ID of record.

Answer (score 1):

Update/Create the SP like

```
CREATE PROC SP_Insert
(
     @name VARCHAR(50),
     @id INT OUTPUT
)

AS 
    INSERT INTO Table (ColumnName) VALUES (@name)
    SET @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and then call this sp from ado.net like below

```
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "SP_Insert";
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    param.Name = "@id";
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int id = (int)param.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the stored proc/command you use to insert a new record, you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to return the last generated identity value:

```
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)
```

If you're using a stored proc and cannot modify it, you need to use `@@IDENTITY`, as `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` works only in the same scope (in this case within a stored proc). Be careful though, as `@@IDENTITY` will return the last identity not limited by scope which can be affected e.g. by triggers.

```
SELECT CAST(@@IDENTITY AS INT)
```

More on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Comment: You should never use @@IDENTITY, should use SCOPE_IDENTITY() in the same request as the insert. @@IDENTITY will return invalid results if you have triggers or other inserts occurring.

Comment: But `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` won't work if the original insert was in a stored proc. You would have to put it into the stored proc. Thanks anyway, I will update my answer to make it clear.